# Inputenc not working inside included file

Tags: input-encodings, multiple-files

So in the document section ű ő letter work perfectly fine, but inside another tex file which is included with \include{myothertexfile} into the document, is not working. Some of the documents inside my project is working with this way, and some of them replaces ű with ?. And if i try to add a new document, the compiling fails cuz of the input text is latin2.

Here is my project: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AqdZJMIRBGu7yw6RJk_OyA9zyUzD

Comment: Hello, welcome to TeX.SE. Your files don't use the same encoding. Many of them appear to be in latin1 (ISO 8859-1), but `chapter3.tex`, `mychapter.tex` and `diploma.tex` use ISO 8859-2, according to Emacs' autodetection mechanism. All files should have an encoding that matches what you declare to `inputenc`.

Comment: if you definitely want to use latin2 rather than utf-8 that is supported, just use `\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}` but utf-8 is recommended